# Remove personal data but keep OS and other installed software

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to completely remove everything from a computer, without re-installing?](https://superuser.com/questions/195760/whats-the-best-way-to-completely-remove-everything-from-a-computer-without-re)

I want to remove all data, cookies etc. from a PC I'm giving to a friend.

I want Microsoft Office and tools to remain.  I would like to select other applications to delete or keep.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new user account for your friend (with administrative rights), switch into that account, and delete your old account. This should remove the `C:\Users\Jerry` folder,  which contains all your files and application settings.